# TensorFlow 2 with tf.dataset pipeline -- Error on Prediction -- AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor(...)

Tags: tensorflow, prediction

I have multiple input/multiple output TF model with tf.dataset as the input mechanism. It works well while training, but when running prediction it returns AssertionError

AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("outputs/Identity:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32)

I tried multiple structures of the input tuple but nothing works.

How can I fix it? I want to keep the tf.dataset as the input mechanism

below is a minimum model structure:

"""
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

```
    # MODEL DEFINITION
    def create_model_multiple():

        input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,), name = 'I1')
        input2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(6,), name = 'I2')
        hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation='relu')(input1)
        hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation='relu')(input2)
        merge = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([hidden1, hidden2])
        hidden3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 3, activation='relu')(merge)
        output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, name ='O1')(hidden3)
        output2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, name ='O2')(hidden3)
        outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis = -1, name='outputs')([output1, output2])

        model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input1,input2], outputs = outputs)

        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                      loss='mse',
                      metrics=['mse'])

        return model

    model = create_model_multiple()


    # TRAINING
    x1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (190,13))
    x2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (190,6))

    y1 = np.random.randint(0,1, 190)
    y2 = np.random.randint(0,1, 190)

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((tf.dtypes.cast(x1, dtype=tf.float32), 
                                                        tf.dtypes.cast(x2, dtype=tf.float32)),        
                                  (tf.dtypes.cast(np.concatenate((np.expand_dims(y1,axis = 1),
                                                                  np.expand_dims(y2,axis = 1)), 
                                                                  axis=1),dtype=tf.float32))))
                      .cache().batch(190).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                epochs=10,
                verbose = 1)

    # PREDICTION

    pred_x1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (50,13))
    pred_x2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (50,6))

    prediction_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.dtypes.cast(pred_x1, 
                          dtype=tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(pred_x2, dtype=tf.float32)))
               .cache().batch(50).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    model.predict(prediction_dataset)
```

"""
Complete Error:

"""
File "", line 56, in 
model.predict(prediction_dataset)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 88, in _method_wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1268, in predict
tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in **call**
result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 627, in _call
self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 506, in _initialize
*args, **kwds))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2667, in _create_graph_function
capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)

AssertionError: in user code:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1147 predict_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1122 predict_step  **
    return self(x, training=False)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:927 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py:719 call
    convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py:899 _run_internal_graph
    assert str(id(x)) in tensor_dict, 'Could not compute output ' + str(x)

AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("outputs/Identity:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32)
```

"""

Comment: I just made it work with introduction of dictionary into the prediction_dataset specification -- still i am looking for a way to set it up only with tuples - it works without dictionaries with single input prediction_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"I1": tf.dtypes.cast(pred_x1, dtype=tf.float32),
                                                    "I2": tf.dtypes.cast(pred_x2, dtype=tf.float32)})).cache().batch(50).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)